# Is there a way to skip my worm's crawling/warping?

Tags: worms-crazy-golf

After every shot, my worm either crawls to the ball (if it's close enough) or teleports to it.  This takes a few seconds each time and after hours of play it's become exceptionally annoying.  Is there a way to skip this and move to the next shot instantaneously?  I didn't see anything in the settings but maybe there's a config file I can edit or something.